# Preview the name an table in EF auto pluralization for an entity

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework-4, fluent-migrator

```
public class PersonInfo : MyTableBase
```

I know that when I use this entity, using CodeFirst convention the table for the entity will be named "PersonInfoes" unless I add the Table attribute.

Is there a way to preview the name of a table given an entity name? I am using fluent-migrator too, if they have a way of doing it. Something like this.

```
var tableName = EF.getAutoCreateName("EntityName") // tableName == "EntityNames"
```

Answer (score 0):

When using code first you control what the names will be.

```
public DbSet<PersonInfo> WhateverYouWantToNameIt { get;set; }
```

Comment: That is the name to access the table set, not the actual table itself.

Comment: @kosmos This is code first and auto pluralization wouldn't really apply. The table name is the name you create. The table set name is the name you give it and this won't be changed by EF. Auto pluralization really applies more to database first or most likely in the case of the poster he is using reverse engineering. Once this is done you can change the name to whatever you like.